# KendoUI set Northwind Demo like

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-gauge

I am using the latest KendoUI, and try to set a gauge like the kendoUI's offical web site AD image shows.

you could find the AD image just at: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui
please see the image, it shows an application named "northwind-dash", and there is a green gauge on it, there is a white color text "63%" inside the gauge.

I try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div id="gauge-container">
                <div id="gauge"></div>

                <input id="gauge-value" value="65">
            </div>

            <script>
                function createGauge() {
                    $("#gauge").kendoRadialGauge({

                        pointer: {
                            value: $("#gauge-value").val()
                        },

                        scale: {
                            minorUnit: 5,
                            startAngle: -30,
                            endAngle: 210,
                            max: 180
                        }
                    });
                }

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    createGauge();

                    function updateValue() {
                        $("#gauge").data("kendoRadialGauge").value($("#gauge-value").val());
                    }

                    if (kendo.ui.Slider) {
                        $("#gauge-value").kendoSlider({
                            min: 0,
                            max: 180,
                            showButtons: false,
                            change: updateValue
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#gauge-value").change(updateValue);
                    }


                    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", function(e) {
                        createGauge();
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <style scoped>
                #gauge-container {
                    background: transparent url("../content/dataviz/gauge/gauge-container-partial.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
                    width: 386px;
                    height: 386px;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
                }

                #gauge {
                    width: 350px;
                    height: 300px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }

                #gauge-container .k-slider {
                    margin-top: -11px;
                    width: 140px;
                }

            </style>
        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

But, I could only get the normal Radial Gauge.
I look everywhere in the KendoUI's document, but can't find anything about the northwind-dash demo or example.

Who knows how to change the style of the Gauge to make it just like the image shows.

yours,
Ivan

Comment: Why do you think that the 63% is part of the gauge and not something printed on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the sources for KendoUI + Northwind application in [GitHub](https://github.com/telerik/kendoui-northwind-dashboard) and you can see a version running in Telerik [ASPNET-MVC demo site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html5-dashboard-sample-app/)

But no, it does not look like the capture that they have, not sure if that's an older version of this project or an internal one.

[image]

Nevertheless, there is no option for placing that percentage and you have to do it manually playing with HTML and CSS.

What you might do is define the Chart using a DataSource like this:

```
$("#value").kendoChart({
    // Define Data Source, the first element is the value to represent,
    //                     the second is 100 - first element.
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            { "value": 63 },
            // The remaining part of the Chart is transparent so we actually
            // only see the first value
            { "value": 37, color: "transparent" }
        ]
    },
    // Define a DataBound event handler used when we change the data and will
    // print the value inside the Chart.
    dataBound: function () {
        // Get current value and compute percentage.
        var percentage = (this.dataSource.at(0).value / 100);
        // Convert percentage to text and place it in inside the chart
        $("#value-label").text(kendo.toString(percentage, "p0"));
    },
    // No legend
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        // Type of series: Donut
        type: "donut",
        // Size of the hole of the Donut
        holeSize: 60,
        // Thickness of the Donut
        size: 20
    },
    series: [
        // The value of the series is in "value" field while the color is 
        // a field called color.
        { field: "value", colorField: "color" }
    ],
    // No tooltip
    tooltip: { visible: false }
});
```

Now, the HTML and CSS definition for placing the label on top of the Chart:

```
<div class="value-container">
    <div id="value"></div>
    <div id="value-label" class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

A container that includes two `DIV` the first for the Chart and the second for the label. In order to display the label on top of the Chart, we define a CSS class `overlay` as follow:

```
    .overlay {
        font-size: 24px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 220px;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Where we specify the size of the label and its position from top and centered horizontally (here I hardcoded the vertical position (`220px`) but you can find for methods for centering a text in a DIV.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/egfrohtx/

Which looks like: [image]